# Using operator overloading inside a function with const type input parameters in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class vec {
  public:
    float x,y;

  vec(float a, float b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
  }

  const vec operator + (const vec & a) {
    vec ResVec(0.0f, 0.0f);
    ResVec.x = x + a.x;
    ResVec.y = y + a.y;

    return ResVec;
  }

};

vec foo(const vec& v1, const vec& v2)
{
    const vec temp(2.0f,2.0f);
    return v1 + v2 + temp;
}

int main() {
  vec v1(1.0f, 1.0f);
  vec v2(2.0f,2.0f);
  vec v3(0.0f,0.0f);

  v3 = foo(v1,v2);
}
```

[Run the above code online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1s0l2b6r)

I want to implement the function `foo` with const input parameters. But I fail, because the compiler says: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const vec’ and ‘const vec’)
     return v1 + v2 + temp. How can I modify the operator overloading so that I can use the + operator in the function

`vec foo(const vec& v1, const vec& v2)`

Comment: Change `const vec operator + (const vec & a)` to `const vec operator + (const vec & a) const`. It tells the compiler that this function does not change anything about the object from that it is called and then it can be called for `const` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const vec operator + (const vec & a) {
```

This overload returns a `const vec`. Not a `vec`. This is important.

```
     v1 + v2 + temp;
```

The first addition operator, thusly, returns a `const vec`. The second addition operator will attempt to add `const vec` to a `vec`. However the overload is not a `const` class method, so it can't be invoked for a `const` object (this is not a 100% technically accurate explanation, see below, but it's easier to understand in this example).

Simply change the overload as:

```
 const vec operator + (const vec & a) const {
```

That's what it should be anyway, since it doesn't modify anything in `this`. There are other reasons why this overload must be a `const` class method; it's easier to understand why, in this case, by considering the fact that `const vec` gets returned. You can also declare this overload as return a `vec` instead of a `const vec`, but that's not a material issue (the same compilation error will occur, for a different reason).

When it comes to declaring operator overloads, the following rule of thumb applies: if the overloaded operator does not modify anything in `this`, you must declare it as a `const` class method.